# if statement in .bashrc not working correctly

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, environment-variables

I set up `.bashrc` to show a long prompt if the terminal is at least 80 characters wide. Otherwise it shows a degraded, smaller prompt.

I use an `if` statement to achieve this:

```
dp_smaller_than=80
if [ $COLUMNS -lt $dp_smaller_than ]
then
    PROMPT_COMMAND="degr_prompt"
else
    PROMPT_COMMAND="full_prompt"
fi
```

It only works correctly if I put a `sleep 0` or other command before this statement, otherwise it shows the following error:

```
[: -lt: unary operator expected
```

**Note:** I have the `degr_prompt` and `full_prompt` functions defined in the beginning of the file.

Comment: can you provide the statement, which sets `COLUMNS`?

Comment: @polym, it is set automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`COLUMNS` variable is set by bash `upon receipt of a SIGWINCH.` (see `Shell Variables` section in `man bash`). It is not set in your script because this is not an environment variable. See yourself:

```
$ export COLUMNS=$COLUMNS
$ ./your-script.sh
```

Now it works. You need to retrieve value of `COLUMNS` in your script. You can use `tput` for example:

```
$ tput cols
186
```

Comment: +1 because of `SIGWINCH` info.

Answer (score 5):

`COLUMNS` is not set somehow in `.bashrc`.

Just get the columns via `tput cols` like this:

```
dp_smaller_than=80
if [ $(tput cols) -lt $dp_smaller_than ]
then
    PROMPT_COMMAND="degr_prompt"
else
    PROMPT_COMMAND="full_prompt"
fi
```

Comment: You're right. Strange, `$COLUMNS` only get set if a command gets executed. I tested it with `echo $COLUMNS`.

Comment: @psimon `man bash`: `checkwinsize - If  set, bash checks the window size after each command and, if necessary, updates the values of LINES and COLUMNS.`. So if you've got `checkwinsize` set, you just need to execute a command (a simple `:` would suffice).

Comment: @Patrick it seems that not all commands work for this. `sleep`, `echo`, `printf` work, but `alias`, `shopt`, `[` or setting variables don't (I have these **before** the `if` statement in `.bashrc`). Is it in connection with interactivity?